# Create Spring Boot test with separate application.properties

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-test

I am developing web app with Spring Boot, and now I am trying to create tests for DAO layer, and I'd like to use different configurations, which will read custom property file instead of standard one. But Iam having trouble with that, it always reads default application. and hibernate.properties. 
The want to do it in order to have  different hibernate.ddl-auto properties for test. But when I run the test, I see that Spring reads properties from the hibernate.properties which is in resource folder (I've purposely made a typo in that file in order to get exception if it was read by Spring). But why does it read that file even when I use `@TestPropertySource`? 
 I see there's something that I don`t know about that, but what?
package src/test/java/com.guard/dao

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Rollback

public class LifeguardDaoTest {
    @Autowired
    private LifeguardDao lgDao;

    @Test
    public void selectTest(){
        for (Lifeguard lg :lgDao.getAll()) {
            System.out.println(lg);
        }
    }
}`
```

Test configuration class is to setup context
package src/test/java/com.guard

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(value = {"com.guard.dao","com.guard.model"})
@TestPropertySource(value = {"classpath:application-test.properties", "classpath:hibernate-test.properties"})
public class TestConfiguration {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(TestConfiguration.class, args);
        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        System.out.println("Spring boot test generated " + beanNames.length + " beans");

    }
}
```

Required application-test.properties and hibernate-test.properties are on src/test/java path 
Here's project structure (don`t know how to design it here, sorry)

```
|src
|--main
|----java
|------com.guard
|----------configuration
|-------------GuardApplication.class (@SpringBootApplication,requires default props)
|--test
|----java
|------application-test.properties
|-------hibernate-test.properties
|-----com.guard
|-------TestConfiguration.class
|-------dao
|---------LifeguardDaoTest.class
```

My application-test.properties
`

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl-auto=create

# even in case if it won`t use "spring.jpa" prefix
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

`

Answer (score 3):

Create new resources directory inside test directory and put your test properties file there. Also rename your properties files to application.properties and hibernate.properties

Spring tests will take properties from test/resources/ directory. And in this approach, you do not need @TestPropertySource

Answer (score 0):

Typically, @TestPropertySource is used in conjunction with @ContextConfiguration.

Try with this configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@Profile("test")
public class TestConfiguration {

}
```

And annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")
public @interface IntegrationTest { }
```

Then you just write test like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@IntegrationTest
public class SomeDaoTest {
...
}
```